# How to convert a command of curl to pycurl

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

There will be some log when I use pycurl. But I can use "curl -s" to let the log not show if I use curl. How should I do to discard the log if I use pycurl?
The original curl command is just as follows:

```
curl -u user_id:password -T file_path URI
```

The file_path is the path of the file to upload and the URI is the target path. Actually, the protocol used is FTP. I want to upload a file to the server and the server only supports the FTP to upload files. Besides, I can not upload files from local, thus I choose to use pycurl.

Comment: Please show your original `curl` command in your question, give a lot more details: what HTTP protocol, what Python version, what operating system and some some Python code as [mre]

Comment: Would recommend to use an FTP-client in Python, e.g. Python's internal [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html).